# Not placing waitFor statement before findBy cause test to fail - React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

```
render(view)
let timerCellsList;
await waitFor(() => {
  lockCellsList = screen.getAllByTestId('TimerCell');
  expect(lockCellsList).toHaveLength(2);
});

const startTimerButton = within(timerCellsList[1]).getByRole('button');
userEvent.click(startTimerButton);
await waitFor(() => {}, {timeout: 0}); // the test passes with this line and fails without it.
                                       // I can set the timeout to any number including 0.
const activeTimer = await screen.findByRole('cell', {name: /00:00/i});
expect(activeTimer).toBeInTheDocument();
```

I've written a test for which the user clicks a button. The button then makes a network request and on a 200 response it displays a timer which begins to count up in seconds. I'm using MSW to return mock responses to these requests. As the network request is clearly asynchronous, I'm searching for this timer by awaiting a call to screen.findByRole. The issue I'm having is that the test only seems to pass if I separate the call to `userEvent.click(startTimerButton)` and the call too `await screen.findByRole('cell', {name: /00:00/i})` with a call too `await waitFor(() => {})`. It seems that this test will only pass if I let it sleep for any amount of time before searching for the timer. I don't understand why I wouldn't just be able to start searching for the timer immediately.

Without the waitFor statement, the error message I get back is:

> Error: thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
> Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
> var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I would prefer to not have to hack around it as I'm doing now.

I have also tried changing my await findBy to a getBy wrapped inside a waitFor statement but that hasn't worked either. It seems I do just have to allow it to sleep for any amount of time before beginning the search

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `await` in this line:

```js
userEvent.click(startTimerButton);
```

So try:

```js
await userEvent.click(startTimerButton);
```

the `userEvent` API is async since version 14.

Comment: I'm using 13.5.0 of @testing-library/user-event and 12.1.5 of @testing-library/react